# Collect gaps in a number sequence in Rust using Vec::windows

Tags: rust, vectors

I have the following code which collects gaps in a number sequence into a separate `vec`.

There will never be a case, iterating over a `Vec<i32>` where `.windows(2)` will yield a window with `None` values. So I want to simplify things by transforming each window into a `Gap` with first and last `i32` values wherever the gap between 2 numbers is > 1. So a `transform -> filter -> result` kind of pipeline.

My version works, but seems imperative and long-winded. I keep thinking I should be able to use `.from_fn()`, `.filter()` and `.collect()` to generate the `gap` vector without a `for` loop. How would I go about this?

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Gap {
    first: i32,
    last: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let original_numbers = vec![1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 6, 19, 20, 21];
    let mut seq = original_numbers.clone();
    seq.sort();
    let windows = seq.windows(2);
    let mut gaps: Vec<Gap> = Vec::new();
    for gap_window in windows {
        let g = Gap {
            first: if let Some(num) = gap_window.first() { *num + 1 } else { 0 },
            last: if let Some(num) = gap_window.last() { *num - 1 } else { 0 },
        };
        if g.last - g.first >= 0 {
            gaps.push(g)
        }
    }
    for gap in gaps {
        println!("{:?}", gap)
    };

}
```

Output:

```
Gap { first: 2, last: 2 }
Gap { first: 5, last: 5 }
Gap { first: 9, last: 9 }
Gap { first: 12, last: 12 }
Gap { first: 14, last: 18 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My version works, but seems imperative and long-winded. I keep thinking I should be able to use .from_fn(), .filter() and .collect() to generate the gap vector without a for loop. How would I go about this?

Use `filter_map`. It combines filter and map, and what you are doing is essentially mapping windows into gaps and filtering out invalid gaps.

```
first: if let Some(num) = gap_window.first() { *num + 1 } else { 0 },
```

Rust has nice functions for dealing with `Option`. In this case you can do:

```
first: gap_window.first().map(|num| *num  + 1).unwrap_or(0)
```

But why are defaulting to zero here? Silently defaulting to garbage values when an unexpected outcome occours is the worst possible strategy. It is way way better to panic:

```
first: *gap_window.first().unwrap() + 1
```

Or even better:

```
first: gap_window[0] + 1
```

Comment: good pointers. `filter_map()` not appropriate because the `Gap` structs are needed later on, but good to know about `filter_map()` for the same project. How does `gap_window[0] + 1` unwrap the `Option`?

Comment: The fact that `Gap` structs are needed later doesn't prevent `filter_map` from working. See https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3ae9832e78f5363e48351fa0a3e4c665. But in this case filter and then map is actually better.

Comment: @Nick, `gap_window[0]` effectively means `gap_window.get(0).unwrap()` The language designers decided that when indexing into slices it would panic on out of bounds rather than returning an option.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Winston Ewert's answer. My final version below. Note that `filter_map()` was not appropriate because the output and the filter expression are different.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Gap {
    first: i32,
    last: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let original_numbers = vec![1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 6, 19, 20, 21, 22];
    let mut seq = original_numbers.clone();
    seq.sort();
    let windows = seq.windows(2);
    let mut gaps = windows.into_iter().map(|win| Gap {
            first: win.first().unwrap() + 1,
            last: win.last().unwrap() - 1
        }).filter(|gap| gap.last - gap.first >= 0);
    for gap in gaps {
        println!("{:?}", gap)
    };
}
```

Output:

```rust
Gap { first: 2, last: 2 }
Gap { first: 5, last: 5 }
Gap { first: 9, last: 9 }
Gap { first: 12, last: 12 }
Gap { first: 14, last: 18 }
```